# Is there a way to create monthly subscription via flutter and stripe?

Tags: firebase, flutter, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I am creating an app for my practice with monthly subscriptions and each subscription. I have already combined it with firebase. The regular purchase part is done, however I've no idea about how to handle monthly subscriptions in flutter-stripe. There is already code available in stripe-docs here in node, C#, Go, python etc. Here's the link: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout/fixed-price; genuinely speaking, I'm not understanding these codes. That's why I want to know that is there anyway to make recurring payment via the flutter-stripe duo. If there is, then please tell me. Here's the code for only one time purchase:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart';
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

class StripeService{
  final HttpsCallable intent = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('createPaymentIntent');
  User user;
  DocumentReference userDocReference;

  StripePayments(this.user) {
    user != null ? userDocReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("User").doc(user.uid)
    : user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    userDocReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("User").doc(user.uid);
  }

  startPaymentProcess(double amount) {
    StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(CardFormPaymentRequest()).then((paymentMethod) {
      amount *= 100.0; // multipliying with 100 to change $ to cents
      intent.call(<String, dynamic>{'amount': amount, 'currency': 'usd'}).then(
          (response) {
            _cnfrmPayment(response.data["client_secret"],
            paymentMethod); //function for confirmation for payment
      });
    });
  }

  _cnfrmPayment(String clientSecret, PaymentMethod paymentMethod, context) {
    StripePayment.confirmPaymentIntent(PaymentIntent(
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
      paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
   )
  ).then((intentResult) {
      userDocReference.set({
        "status": intentResult.status,
        "paymentMethodId": intentResult.paymentMethodId,
        "paymentIntentId": intentResult.paymentIntentId
      });
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Payment done successfully")
        )
      );
    });
  }

  confirmDialog(String clientSecret, PaymentMethod paymentMethod, context) {
    var confirm = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Confirm Payement"),
      content: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Make Payment",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
            Text("Charge amount:\$100")
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('CANCEL'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text('Payment Cancelled'),
            );
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: new Text('Confirm'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            _cnfrmPayment(
            clientSecret, paymentMethod); // function to confirm Payment
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return confirm;
        }
     );
  }
}
```

My firebase function which I've copied from this https://medium.com/@hamza39460/stripe-payments-in-flutter-cb2f9cb053d1 medium post. I've deployed this function in node 8, since node >= 10 run only on blaze plan in firebase and I am a student. Here's full code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings)
const stripe = require('stripe')('MY_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');
exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: data.amount,
        currency: data.currency,
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
    });
});
```

Comment: Subscriptions need to be created via a backend call with your secret key, so you would use Firebase in your setup to make that call. There's a (non-Flutter) working example at https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-stripe-subscriptions

Comment: @taintedzodiac the extension requires you to be on blaze plan in firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an existing package that you can use to implement this kind of function.

[flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe):

> The Stripe Flutter SDK allows you to build delightful payment
> experiences in your native Android and iOS apps using Flutter. We
> provide powerful and customizable UI screens and elements that can be
> used out-of-the-box to collect your users' payment details.

You can also follow [this blog](https://mypace-co-ltd.medium.com/use-flutter-stripe-for-payment-and-subscription-registration-without-a-backend-9c503ed86fdd) for some helpful guide on implementing payments using the package.